# zeroes and ones are automatically typed in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard, keyboard-events

I came across this peculiar issue. Every time I type '(' in a terminal or vi editor, automatically 9's are typed in and the typing of 9 stops when I interrupt it by typing any key. 
Example : (999999999999999999999999999... stops after I press a key.

Similarly, when I type ')', zeroes are automatically typed in and stops only after I interrupt it by typing a key. What is causing this? How can I fix it? I tried to Google around, but didn't find anything related.

Edit : Also noticed that, while the numbers 9 or 0 are being inserted, by pressing and holding shift(only) button, it prints either a ( or ) respectively. Releasing the shift button, 9s or 0s are inserted again.

Also, this issue happens when I release the shift button before the number 9 while trying to insert '('. Same with 0 and ')'. If I release 9 or 0 first, this issue doesn't occur.

Comment: Sometime (i have no idea if this will work in your own case), the command $ stty sane clears up terminal behavior.

Comment: Have you ruled out a problem with your keyboard (unplugged it, replugged it in, swapped with another), logged out and back in? Rebooted? Sometimes weird behaviors like that can be fixed that those ways.

Comment: Thanks. Will try rebooting and see. But it may not be a keyboard issue as it works fine other times. This behavior occurs every sometimes. Previously I didn't bother to figure out what the issue could be. Now it's really irritating me.

Comment: But how would it merely being and intermittent indicate if the problem was in the keyboard, or in the computer, or OS?  Why do you assume the fact that it comes and goes means it's not a problem with the keyboard? Could be a bad cable or connector too, or in the USB hardware. What hardware/OS?

Comment: I just tried with a different keyboard! The same issue persists.